# Angular 8 do I need to subscribe to a request if I don't care about the response

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-subscriptions

I hope this makes sense.
I have decided to change the way some of my services are working simply because it was becoming a bit cumbersome to subscribe to responses and handle creates, updates and deletes in different views. So I decided to make a generic service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '@environments/environment';
import { Resource } from '../models/resource';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService<T extends Resource> {
    items: BehaviorSubject<T[]>;

    constructor(private endpoint: string, private http: HttpClient, private toastr: ToastrService) {
        this.items = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>([]);
    }

    initialize(feedId: number) {
        return this.http.get<T[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/feeds/${feedId}/${this.endpoint}`).pipe(
            map(response => {
                console.log(this.endpoint, response);
                this.items.next(response);
                return response;
            }),
        );
    }

    get(id: number) {
        return this.http.get<T>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
    }

    create(filter: T) {
        return this.http.post<T>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}`, filter).pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                const message = response.message;
                const item = response.model;

                let items = this.items.value;
                items.push(item);

                this.emit(items, message);

                return response.model;
            }),
        );
    }

    update(filter: T) {
        return this.http.put<T>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}`, filter).pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                const message = response.message;
                const item = response.model;

                let items = this.items.value;
                this.remove(items, filter.id);
                items.push(item);

                this.emit(items, message);

                return response.model;
            }),
        );
    }

    delete(id: number) {
        return this.http.delete<string>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`).pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                let items = this.items.value;
                items.forEach((item, i) => {
                    if (item.id !== id) return;
                    items.splice(i, 1);
                });

                this.emit(items, response);

                return response;
            }),
        );
    }

    private remove(items: T[], id: number) {
        items.forEach((item, i) => {
            if (item.id !== id) return;
            items.splice(i, 1);
        });
    }

    private emit(items: T[], message: string) {
        this.items.next(items);
        this.toastr.success(message);
    }
}
```

The idea behind this service is that the **initialize** method is called only once, when it has been called, you can see that it maps the response to the **items** array within the service itself. Then when a create, update or delete is performed, it is that array that is changed.

That would (in theory) allow any component to subscribe to the **items** array to get updated with any changes.

So, I have a few services that "extend" this service, for example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Filter } from '@models';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FilterService extends DataService<Filter> {
    constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, toastr: ToastrService) {
        super('filters', httpClient, toastr);
    }
}
```

So far, so good. So, my question is: Do I have to call the **initialize** method and invoke a subscription?

For example, currently I have this component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { FilterService } from '@services';
import { NgAnimateScrollService } from 'ng-animate-scroll';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-feed-filters',
    templateUrl: './filters.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./filters.component.scss'],
})
export class FiltersComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() feedId: number;
    displayForm: boolean;

    constructor(private animateScrollService: NgAnimateScrollService, private filterService: FilterService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initialize();
    }

    navigateToForm() {
        this.displayForm = true;
        this.animateScrollService.scrollToElement('filterSave');
    }

    private initialize(): void {
        this.filterService
            .initialize(this.feedId)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(() => {});
    }
}
```

As you can see with the private method, I `pipe`, then `first` and then `subscribe` which is what I would do if I want to get the results from there. In my "child" component, I have this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Filter } from '@models';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from '@core';
import { FilterService } from '@services';
import { FiltersSaveComponent } from './filters-save.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-filters',
    templateUrl: './filters.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./filters.component.scss'],
})
export class FiltersComponent implements OnInit {
    filters: Filter[];

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private filterService: FilterService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.filterService.items.subscribe(filters => (this.filters = filters));
    }

    openModal(id: number) {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.message = 'Deleting a filter is irreversible. Do you wish to continue?';
        modalRef.result.then(
            () => {
                this.filterService.delete(id);
            },
            () => {
                // Do nothing
            },
        );
    }

    openSaveForm(filter: Filter) {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(FiltersSaveComponent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.feedId = filter.feedId;
        modalRef.componentInstance.filterId = filter.id;
        modalRef.componentInstance.modal = true;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I subscribe to the **items** array from the **filterService**.
So, in my parent controller, I figure I don't actually need the subscription, but if I remove it it doesn't work.

I thought I would be able to do something like:

```
private initialize(): void {
    this.filterService.initialize(this.feedId);
}
```

instead of

```
private initialize(): void {
    this.filterService
        .initialize(this.feedId)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(() => {
            // I don't need this
        });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just the way I have to do it?
I hope I explained myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call `subscribe` on any request method on the `HttpClient` for the request to be sent. The `HttpClient` returns a cold observable which means it won't run until something subscribes to it (as opposed to a hot observable that starts running immediately).

Additionally, an observable from the the `HttpClient` will only ever emit one value, the response, which means piping it to `first` is unneccessary. Your final logic will look something like this:

```js
this.filterService.initialize(this.feedId).subscribe(() => undefined);
```

Alternatively, instead of subscribing where the service is used you can instead subscribe in the `DataService` and then your call will look like:

```js
this.filterService.initialize(this.feedId);
```

A nice thing about the `HttpClient` is that the observables they return will never emit again so there is no need to keep track of the subscription and close it later.